# Iterating through columns with conditionals

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently trying to iterate through 38 columns titled 'Switch 1, Switch 2, ....' in order to update them based on a condition.

Here's my code:

```
DECLARE @i int
DECLARE @selec nvarchar(max)

SET @i  = 1

WHILE @ i <= 38
    BEGIN
        SET @selec = 'UPDATE 'Catalog v4'' + '
        SET   'Switch' + LTRIM(STR(@i+1)) = ' + CASE
        WHEN ( 'Switch' + LTRIM(STR(@i+1))= [Switch Check String] ) THEN ( '' )
        ELSE ( 'Switch' + LTRIM(STR(@i+1))) 
        SET @i = @i+1
        EXEC(@selec)
     END
```

I keep getting an error

> Must declare scalar variable @, incorrect syntax near Recipe

Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Tables with repeating groups are almost always a sign of a poor database design. Normalizing such tables to first normal form almost always makes them easier to work with.

Comment: You need to print @selec and observe what's wrong with it. You've built an SQL statement but it has a syntax error in it.

Comment: I suppose I should clarify that this is a data manipulation software that allows you to make custom macros with SQL. Intent isn't to make a database with this information, more of a processing purpose.

Comment: @TroyE219 No idea what _a data manipulation software_ means. But to debug dynamic sql you must see what you are trying to execute. What you have is full of tsql syntax errors so it is not clear what you are doing nor how you are doing it. And note that 'Switch 1' is not the same as 'Switch1' - your code generates the latter while you write the former. A column name with a space in it requires special handling.

Comment: The error is because you have a space between the @ and the i in  `WHILE @ i <= 38`

Comment: Even if you fix that, there's more errors in that SQL, @Wouter .

Comment: T-SQL is a lousy language to do string processing in. This applies particularly when said string processing is intended to generate more T-SQL. If at all possible, try moving code generation to the client side. While client-side code generation is often associated with SQL injection, this really only applies if you're inserting strings supplied externally, not when you're processing metadata generated by SQL Server itself.

Comment: Is "Catalog" spelled "Recipe" in your actual code? The error message doesn't make sense with respect to the "code" you posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHILE @ i <= 38
```

Should Be:

```
 WHILE @i <= 38
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to update table [Catalog 4], following might help:

```
DECLARE @i int
DECLARE @selec nvarchar(max)

SET @i  = 1

WHILE @i <= 38
    BEGIN
        SET @selec = 'UPDATE '+QUOTENAME('Catalog v4')+'
        SET   '+QUOTENAME('Switch ' + LTRIM(STR(@i+1)))+' =  CASE
        WHEN ('+QUOTENAME('Switch '+ LTRIM(STR(@i+1)))+' = ''[Switch Check String]'' ) THEN ( '''' )
        ELSE ('+QUOTENAME('Switch ' + LTRIM(STR(@i+1)))+') END'
        
        PRINT @selec    --please check the printed messages before executing those.

        SET @i = @i+1
        --EXEC(@selec)
     END
```

- `Quotename` helps in defining object names correctly if there are spaces in them.
- Please replace the [Switch check string] accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The following code creates a template statement, then updates it each time through the loop rather than trying to assemble it from bits'n'pieces each time.

```
declare @SQLTemplate as VarChar(256) =
  'update [Catalog V4] set Switch# = '' where Switch# = [Switch Check String];'
declare @SQL as VarChar(256);
declare @Index as Int = 1;

while @Index <= 38
  begin
  set @SQL = Replace( @SQLTemplate, '#', Cast( @Index as VarChar(3) ) );
  execute ( @SQL );
  set @Index += 1;
  end
```

Note that the `update` statement has been simplified to avoid updating every row on every pass, regardless of whether the value actually changes.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (requires thorough testing) is to use the Information.Schema.Columns View instead of a loop.

```
    declare @select varchar(4000) = ''

    select  
    @select = @select 
    + 'update YourTableName set ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = ' + ' CASE WHEN ' + COLUMN_NAME 
    + ' = ''[Switch Check String]'' THEN '''' ELSE ' + COLUMN_NAME + 'END ; '
    
    FROM 

    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    where 
    TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName' 
    and COLUMN_NAME like 'YourCondition'
    
    print @select
    --exec @select
```